# Unexpected end in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following has an unexpected end that I just can't find! Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated. Errors are:

`C:/Sites/rails_projects/blog/app/models/user.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end`

`app/controllers/users_controller.rb:`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Post your `User` model as well please.

Comment: the error is not in this class

Comment: The error is clearly in your User model. Check that

Answer (score 0):

Generally means you'll have a syntax error in a file

As the comments have pointed out, the file in question will be `user.rb`

I'd surmise you've either forgotten to include an `end` tag, or have a syntax error in your `User` model